# Can an __attribute__ specifier be used with both the function prototype and the function definition?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, armcc

My question directly pertains to the `__attribute__((noreturn))` but more generally could pertain to others as well - such as `__attribute__(noinline)`.  I have looked at both the gcc manual and the Keil compiler reference guide to determine what the proper syntax is for using `__attribute__` with a function.  What I have generally seen is the following:

```
void function (void) __attribute__((noreturn));  //Prototype has __attribute__

void function (void)                             //Definition does not.
{
    while (1);
}
```

I have also seen the `__attribute__` used before the function definition as follows:

```
__attribute__((noreturn)) void function (void)
{
    while (1);
}
```

However, I have not seen an example of it used with both the function prototype and the function definition.  I think having the `__attribute__` in both locations would result in better code readability; I would know by looking at either the function prototype or the definition that an attribute has been applied.  The result would be as follows:

```
__attribute__((noreturn)) void function (void) ;  //Prototype has __attribute__

__attribute__((noreturn)) void function (void)    //Definition has __attribute__
{                                               //as well.
    while (1);
}
```

I have successfully compiled code with the Keil armcc compiler using my aforementioned method.  Is there any reason why I should **not** use this method with either armcc or gcc?

Comment: well it is up to the compiler... and i would think it would change depending on the directive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a snippet from the GCC 4.0 docs available [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

```
The keyword __attribute__ allows you to specify special attributes when making a
declaration.
```

Note it says 'declaration' not 'definition'. [This](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/gnu-c-attributes.html) older Unix Wiz article also has lots of good advice. It also says to use attributes in declarations.

Comment: For completeness the current docs are here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: On debian's gcc 10.2.1, attributes can be used in function declarations, but the attribute must come before the declarator, ie. precede the function signature. I don't know if both can be used as asked.

Answer (score 1):

As Sean Perry says, it would appear that **GCC** only specifies that special attributes can be used with declarations.

I was digging some more into the **ARMCC** docs and finally found what I was looking for [here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armccref/armccref_chdfibbi.htm):

> > You can set these function attributes in the declaration, the definition, or both.

So, for ARMCC *my* use of `__attribute__` as shown in the OP is safe, but that is not true for GCC.

Comment: Thanks for the ARMCC bit. I was not familiar enough with it or its docs. Since you asked for either, I figured mentioning it was not proper use with GCC was sufficient.

Comment: @Sean Good point.  You did answer my question regarding GCC so I have selected yours as the correct answer.  Thanks for finding the info for me.  I read that section of the GCC docs before I even asked the question, but I had 'prototype' on my brain and wasn't thinking 'declaration'.  Good find.